# select from if column empty select another one

Tags: oracle, select

i have table product with attr: `Id, discount_pct, price, number_of_sold`.

`discount_pct` can be `null`.

I am trying to make select query to sum `discount_pct * price * number_of_sold`, if `discount_pct` is not NULL, otherwise, sum `price * number_of_sold`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
SUM( coalesce( (1 - discount_pct/100) * price, price ) * number_of_sold )
```

assuming that `discount_pct` is a value between 0 and 100 (i.e. 20 indicates a 20% discount).   `(1 - discount_pct/100) * price` will compute the discounted price if `discount_pct` is non-NULL or NULL if `discount_pct` is NULL.  `coalesce` returns the first non-NULL value in the list.  So the full expression returns the discounted price if it can be computed or the price if it cannot multiplied by the number sold.